# How do I access an argparse parameter with a space from a namespace?

Tags: python, argparse

```
import argparse
from signal import default_int_handler

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Parse arguments into client file", formatter_class = argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

parser.add_argument('-p port', nargs = '?', default = 27993, type = int)
parser.add_argument('-s', nargs = '?', default = False)
parser.add_argument('hostname')


args = parser.parse_args()


print(args.p_port)
```

In something like this, when I try to access the `p_port` argument, I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute '_p_port'

Comment: use something simpler than `'-p port`.  And do `print(args)` to see what is actually in `args`

Comment: Why do you need the space?

Comment: To access attributes with the `args.name` syntax, `name` has to be a valid Python variable name.  If it isn't, due for example to special characters, you can use `getattr(args,name)` or `vars(args)[name]`.  But the space is going to create problems at the bash level, unless you quote it, e.g. `python myscript.py '-p port' 23424`.  Keep the flag string simple, and use `metavar` or `help` to make things more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally,

1. a single dash is used for single-letter flags,
2. a double dash is used for flags with multi-letter names, and
3. flags *never* have spaces in them.

(1) and (2) are quite frequently broken, but breaking (3) is going to cause you no end of headaches. I *strongly* recommend that you make that parameter name `--p-port` or `--p_port`.